# row bind or annotate a dataframe, based on matching using between, on columns

Tags: r, if-statement, subset, between

My data looks more or less like this:

```
dictionary <- data.frame(fruit =  c("apple", "banana", "kiwi"), 
                         min_range = c(1, 520, 1200), 
                         max_range=  c(519, 900, 1800))

data <- data.frame(dictionary_id = c(12,600,1500, 3050, 2))
```

I would like to annotate the data frame `data` using the `dictionary` min and max ranges. using dplyr's between doesn't work, as I would be passing it a column, which it doesn't accept.
My approach would be to create an if_else statement inside a mutate(), which would in principle work like this:

```
data %>%
  mutate(fruit = if_else(dictionary_id >= dictionary$min_range & dictionary_id <= dictionary$max_range,
                          dictionary$fruit,
                          "error"))
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin`

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(data, dictionary, 
                            by = c('dictionary_id' = 'min_range', 'dictionary_id' = 'max_range'), 
                            match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`))

#  dictionary_id  fruit min_range max_range
#1            12  apple         1       519
#2           600 banana       520       900
#3          1500   kiwi      1200      1800
```